# Drawing a specific card from a repeatedly reshuffled deck

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Suppose I want a card A from a deck. I shuffle a deck and draw a card. The probability that this card is $A$ is $1/52$.

Now, suppose I reshuffle this deck n times and draw a card each time. I intend to find the mean number of times I would draw card $A$. Would I have to model this as a Binomial random variable $A$~$Bin(n,1/52)$? And what kind of a random process is this? Bernoulli?

Answer (score 0):

Define success as drawing card $A$.

Binomial distribution $Bin(n, \frac1{52})$ answer the question out of $n$ independent and identical draws, how many would be card $A$.

The mean would be $\frac{n}{52}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ denote the number of times that you draw this card, then:

- $P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{52}\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{52}\right)^{n-k}$
- $E(X)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot P(X=k)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}k\cdot\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{52}\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{52}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{n}{52}$

Answer (score 0):

$p(\text{card A}) = \frac{1}{52}$

$q(\text{Not card A}) = 1 - \frac{1}{52} = \frac{51}{52}$

We have direct formula to find mean of binominal distribution.

Mean = np

n is the number of times you shuffle.

Mean = $n * \frac{1}{52} = \frac{n}{52}$